# Yii. Internationalization in the twig pattern

Tags: yii, twig

How can I pass a method Yii::t() in the twig pattern?
To be able to use it.
for example:

```
{{Yii.t('main', 'some_text')}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already figured out myself.
Who can come in handy:
in the file: / protected / extensions / ETwigViewRenderer.php in init function to add:

> $Yii = new ETwigViewRendererStaticClassProxy ('Yii');
>   $this->_twig-> addGlobal ('lang', $Yii);

In Twig templates used in the following way:

> {{lang.t ('main', 'Login') }}
>   {{lang.t ('main', 'Logout ({username})',{'{username}': App.user.name}) }}

Comment: i think what you mean is

{{lang.t('main', 'Login') }}

Answer (score 3):

```
'viewRenderer' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yiiext.renderers.twig.ETwigViewRenderer',
        'registerAutoloader' => false,
        'globals' => array(
            'html' => 'CHtml'
        ),
        'functions' => array(
            't' => 'Yii::t',
        ),
    ),
```

Then you can use t('main', 'Some text') on your twig files

Answer (score 0):

@extends Eugene answer.

Better to define global in config and not to edit extensions files:

```
'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html', 'lang' => 'Yii'],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Notice 'lang' => 'Yii', in 'globals' setup.